# init function inside directive controller runs continuously

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-modal, angular-controller

I am trying to make  a directive to open a modal so i have written code to open modal inside controller of directive.But it runs continuously and browser stops responding.

```
fileUploadApp.directive('showPopUp',function($uibModal) {
        return {
            restrict: 'ECA',
            controller:  function () {
                console.log("$uibModal",$uibModal);
                var modalInstance=null;
                var init =function(){
                    modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                          animation: false,
                          templateUrl: 'popUpContent.html',
                        });

                     modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
                            console.log("selectedItem",selectedItem);
                        }, function () {
                        });

                }
            init();
            },
            link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
            }  
        }
    });
```

So please suggest how will I implement this functionality and fix this issue.

Comment: You're sure the templateUrl is correct and it loads the correct HTML file without errors? Maybe it reloads the main page if it can't find the popup and tries to initialize itself again in a continuous loop. Or do you have another `fileUploadApp` directive in `popUpContent.html`. Please provide a Plunker for further help.

Comment: How do you use your directive ?
When you want to open a modal ?

Comment: Yeah, It was a cyclic call  ,calling different page done the trick.